# Zooming does not work in my text editors

Tags: 20.04, gedit, vim, text, zooming

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> are not working in my text editors, e.g. `vim`, `gedit` and `nano` on Ubuntu 20.04.0. It works perfectly in browsers such as Chrome, Mozilla, etc.

Comment: So what is the question? It is not expected to work there.

Comment: That depends on the terminal emulator you use.

Comment: i use the  dafault terminal of ubuntu aand also use terminator but still not work like zooming not work in terminal and gedit but working good in browsers and pictures (zooming mean crl  + + and crl + -

Answer (score 1):

According to a [blog post on iTecTec](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-zoom-in-and-out-of-text-in-gedit/), use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y gedit-plugin-text-size
```

This adds the needed plugin.  Then you can activate it in your preferences settings and you should be good.